# What causes substr to fail?

Tags: php, substr

A simple substr call is not functioning properly. I want to grab only the strings which end with a forward slash. Here are seven strings.

```
HELLO/NN, SMILE/JJ, JUMP/, GOOD/RB, GREAT/JJ, HAPPY/NNP, SEAPORT/


$m = substr($string, -1);

 if ($m = "/") {
     echo $string;
 }
```

This code somehow returns true every time. All seven words are printed.
I've tried strrev and many other string functions. It doesn't seem to 
matter. I can literally print $m and see that it's "/" but the if statement
decides that every word meets the $m = "/" criteria. Even when $m is not a "/"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`:

```
if ($m == "/") {
     echo $string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't that be `==` rather than `=`?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($m = "/") {
```

You are assigning the value "/" to $m and that evaluation returns true. You want to compare and should use

```
if ($m == "/") {
```

Comment: This is a revelation to me, I thought = and == were interchangeable. An import from the Qbasic ancient days.